# System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MongoDB.Bson.Bson Document>' does not contain a definition for 'limit'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a DataGrid.I am doing paging.I am using MongoDB.So I wrote query in c# as

```
 var server = MongoServer.Create(this.connectionString);
                server.Connect();
                var db = server.GetDatabase(DATABASE);
                tblRskAlerts = db.GetCollection(RISKALERT_TBL);


   var results = rskTable.Find(query).Skip((pa.paging_PageIndex - 1) * pa.paging_NoOfRecPerPage).limit(pa.paging_NoOfRecPerPage);
```

When I compile I got error as

> Error 13  'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'limit' and no extension method
>   'limit' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\VegaFIXConsoleApp\PravegaVegaFIXConsole\RiskAlert.xaml.cs    214 111 PravegaVegaFIXConsole

Comment: Where do you *expect* it to get a `limit` method from? (That's not even following .NET naming conventions...)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you just want `Take` instead of `limit`. It's unclear to me why you thought there was a `limit` method to start with. (Particularly with that casing, which would have violated .NET naming conventions.)

```
var results = rskTable.Find(query)
                      .Skip((pa.paging_PageIndex - 1) * pa.paging_NoOfRecPerPage)
                      .Take(pa.paging_NoOfRecPerPage);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.I got this query from MongoDB Advanced Queries   [link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-{{skip%28%29}})

Comment: @user768853: that's javascript in that link, not C#.

Comment: The cursor has skip and limit properties. I think the skip and take methods are extensions methods for IEnumerable. If what I think is correct the code `var results = rskTable.Find(query)
                      .Skip(100)
                      .Take(10);` will likely return no results even if you have over 100 documents in your collection because the cursor will execute and return the first 100 result since that is the default. I will test this when I get a chance and update this post.